# What is the Unit type?

Tags: haskell, tuples, template-haskell

Normally in Haskell, tuples of length one aren't allowed (AFAIK). However, when messing with Template Haskell, I got this:

```hs
oneElementTuple = $(do{
    x <- newName "x";
    return $ LamE
        [VarP x]
        (TupE [Just (VarE x)]) -- one element tuple?
})
```

GHCi tells me that `oneElementTuple` is of type `a -> Unit a`. I couldn't find any documentation on this `Unit` type, and it doesn't seem to be an instance of any basic typeclasses like `Show` or `Functor`. So, where is `Unit` defined, if it isn't just built-in magic? Is it at all useful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a [`Unit` type](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.6.1/docs/GHC-Tuple.html#t:Unit) defined in `GHC.Tuple`.

Quoting the source:

```
-- The desugarer uses 1-tuples,
-- but "()" is already used up for 0-tuples
-- See Note [One-tuples] in TysWiredIn
data Unit a = Unit a
```

Nothing fancy. It has no special tuple syntax. It looks like TH uses this type when one tries to make a one-tuple as you did.

Note that since this type in inside a `GHC.` module, it is considered low-level. Normally, when needing one-tuples in everyday programming, one uses the `Identity` newtype instead (which also avoids the additional lifting of  `Unit`).

Comment: What _desugarer_ is being talked about there?

Comment: @leftaroundabout It's one of the internal compiler steps of GHC. I don't know much about it, but I guess it's used after type checking and before Core is generated.

Comment: The `Unit` type has been renamed `Solo`.